# The number of linearly independent holomorphic functions in a multiply connected subset of complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, connectedness

Considering a compact subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, what is the number of linearly independent holomorphic functions defined in this subset?

I find in a [textbook of Algebraic geometry](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=dEzuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22number%20of%20linearly%20independent%20holomorphic%20functions%22&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidksuD6ajpAhWIfd4KHeDZAYEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22number%20of%20linearly%20independent%20holomorphic%20functions%22&f=false) that the number of linearly independent holomorphic functions is equal to the number of connected components of the space. However, there is no more expalanation on this result. Are there any well-established theorem or references on this issue?

Comment: Is the set of holomorphic functions considered a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Also, in the book you refer to, the result is stated for compact algebraic manifolds: no compact subset of the complex plane is a complex manifold.

Comment: @Caffeine Yes, the set of holomorphic functions is considered as a vector space. And I'm sorry for misusing the result.  As the problem is actually from a physical problem of electrostatics, where the "compact subset of complex plane" comes from the region in a 2D conducting cavity with excluding the conductors inside the cavity, I think the domain where the holomorphic function defined can be relaxed appropriately.

Comment: any polynomial is a holomorphic function in any subset of the plane (however one defines holomorphicity on non-open sets) so it is hopeless to think that there are finitely many such unless we have only a few points in the set where the problem is trivial - finitely dimensionality occurs generally on compact algebraic manifolds but as noted, that is not the case here